# How to show a function/command definition in nushell

Tags: nushell

How can I see the definition for a function (aka command)?

In Zsh, I can do this:

```bash
# Define some function
% tarx () { tar xzvf $1 }

# Come back later, see what it is
% declare -f tarx
tarx () { tar xzvf $1 }
```

In nushell, the equivalent seems to be:

```
> def tarx [tb] { tar xzvf $tb }
```

But when I'm poking around to see (and learn) what other commands actually do, I would like to be able to see definitions. Tried `help tarx` which is neat, but seems I need something like a `help def tarx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `view source` [command](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/view_source.html) to "View the source of a custom command":

```bash
def tarx [tb] { tar xzvf $tb }; view source tarx
```

```bash
def tarx [ tb: any ] { tar xzvf $tb }
```

Comment: Thanks! And wow, I also see that `help view source` shows a bunch of nice examples. And shows that it works for aliases and modules too!